# How can I dispatch Google Analytics beacon via Google Tag Manager SDK v4 with Google Play Services?

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-firebase

I'm trying to implement Google Tag Manager and Google Analytics Android SDK v4 with Google Play Services.

I made my sample source based on [this developer guide](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v4/).
It seems that my sample source doesn't include any mis-implementation but it doesn't work well...(see attached source and [my repository](https://github.com/shinhaito/GtmSampleNo1)) 
Actually my sample apps seems to work but cannot dispatch GA tracking beacon with following error messages in LogCat:

**09-16 05:44:42.237      391-663/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Unable to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.START cmp=com.google.android.gms/.analytics.service.AnalyticsService (has extras) } U=0: not found**

I wonder if anyone would have same/similar experiences and how to resolve it?
I attach full LogCat log and my source code in addition this thread. 
Any advices or comments would highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Shin can you find a solution for this?

Comment: Hi, Sorry to have kept you waiting so long. Yes, I found out the reason cause this issue  is SDK version matter. After update Google Play SDK, then it was resolved. I'd like to share you sample source that I saw as a reference. https://github.com/yukoga/GtmSampleNo1 I hope it help you bit.